# is it possible to add arrays to an sql column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Is it possible to add and column to a database that can contain an array? I know in an no sql database you can give array values, but I've never saw it don't in a sql database before.

I want to store two integer values for user permissions, but don't want to store the user info twice. (one for each permission value)

I want to return json something along the lines of

```
{
   "User": "bob",
   "permissions": [0, 3]
}
```

vs

```
{
   "user": "bob",
   "permissions": 0
}
{
   "user": "bob"
   "permissions:  3
}
```

Comment: You can store JSON as a string.  More recent versions of MySQL have better JSON support.  In that sense, the answer is "yes".  But you can't really treat the column as an array in SQL statements.

Comment: Any problem with using a separate table to store the permissions in a many-to-one fashion?

Comment: Ok, so im trying to make an authorization table.  if you have permissions 3 for instance you can log into a business account that relates to your `user_id`, and if you have permissions 0 you can log into a personal user account. basically I'd like to store multiple user id's and multiple and permissions. Would I need to create a row for each permission and each user id?

Comment: If you can choose the values for the permission codes, then you can use powers of two and store them as packed binary in an integer, and use bitwise operators to test, set, and re-set them.

Comment: @TravisHegner no that would be ok. Im just trying limit my db entries to as little as possible for storage size purposes.

Comment: @Jay definitely don't want to duplicate data if you can avoid it. Typically in the relational DB world, you'd create a separate table. You can even make the primary key a combination of `user_id` and `permission`, assuming you don't ever need to store that more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a users table:

```
| user_id | user |
|---------|------|
|        1|  bob |
```

Create a permissions table:

```
| user_id | permission |
|---------|------------|
|        1|           0|
|        1|           3|
```

Then, you can use `join` queries to get the information you need:

```
select * from users u
inner join permissions p 
    on u.user_id=p.user_id
where u.user='bob'
and p.permission=0
```

Comment: yes, I believe this would be the best way of doing it. one things that confused me was when you stated above that I could use the primary key as a combination of `user_id` and `permissions`. what would be the purpose of using them both as a PK?

Comment: Typically, you want to have a unique identifier for each row. That is generally done with a separate column (i.e. `permission_id`). If you know you'll never need to store two separate instances of the same user with the same permission, then you can create the table's primary key using the combination of both `user_id` and `permission`, as that would be unique per row. In either case, you will also want a non-unique index on `user_id` on the permission table to speed up your joins as the table grows.